# How to commit individual messages on success with KafkaJS

Tags: apache-kafka, kafkajs

I am trying to find a similar solution to what `node-rdkafka` does for committing individual messages on success.
In `node-rdkafka` I was able to do call `consumer.commit(message);` after message processing succeeded. What is the equivalent in KafkaJS?

I have so far tried to call `consumer.commitOffsets(...)` inside `eachMessage` handler, but that didn't seem to commit.

I have code like this:

```js
import { Kafka, logLevel } from 'kafkajs';

const kafka = new Kafka({
    clientId: 'qa-topic',
    brokers: [process.env.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER],
    ssl: true,
    logLevel: logLevel.INFO,
    sasl: {
        mechanism: 'plain', 
        username: process.env.KAFKA_CONSUMER_SASL_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.KAFKA_CONSUMER_SASL_PASSWORD
    }
});

const consumer = kafka.consumer({
    groupId: process.env.KAFKA_CONSUMER_GROUP_ID
});

const run = async () => {

    // Consuming
    await consumer.connect()
    await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'my-topic', fromBeginning: true });

    await consumer.run({
        autoCommit: false,
        eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
            try {
                await processMyMessage(message);
                
                // HOW DO I COMMIT THIS MESSAGE?
                // The below doesn't seem to commit 
                // await consumer.commitOffsets([{ topic: 'my-topic', partition, offset:message.offset }]);

            } catch (e) {
                // log error, but do not commit message
            }
        },
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it. Can't use `eachMessage` handler, but instead use `eachBatch` which allows for more flexibility in control in how messages are committed

```js
const run = async () => {
    await consumer.connect();
    await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'my-topic', fromBeginning: true });

    await consumer.run({
        eachBatchAutoResolve: false,
        eachBatch: async ({ batch, resolveOffset, isRunning, isStale }) => {
            const promises = [];
            logger.log(`Starting to process ${batch.messages?.length || 0} messages`);
            for (const message of batch.messages) {
                if (!isRunning() || isStale()) break;
                promises.push(handleMessage(batch.topic, batch.partition, message, resolveOffset));
            }
            await Promise.all(promises);
        },
    });
};
```

Then inside `handleMessage` commit only those messages that succeeded

```js
const handleMessage = async (topic, partition, message, resolveOffset) => {
    try {
      ....
      
      //Commit message if successful 
      resolveOffset(message.offset);
    } catch(e) {
       ...
       // Do not commit 

}
```

Comment: ResolveOffset does not commit the message it just marks the offset. Use commitOffsetIfNecessary in addition to configuring properly the auto commit configuration as I suggested in the answer.

Comment: I'm using a combination of `eachBatchAutoResolve: false`,  `resolveOffset(message.offset)` (in successful message) and keeping the `autoCommit`  as default `true`. According to docs ```resolveOffset() is used to mark a message in the batch as processed. In case of errors, the consumer will automatically commit the resolved offsets.``` . I've ran some tests, and it seems to be committing correctly only when the messages processed successfully. Will run some more tests though

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consuming#a-name-manual-commits-a-manual-committing) states: You can call `consumer.commitOffsets` only after `consumer.run`. You are trying to call it from within the run method, that is why it's not working for you.

Keep in mind that committing after each message increases the network traffic.
If that is a price you are willing to pay you can configure the auto-commit to take care of that for you by setting the `autoCommitThreshold` to 1.

Comment: Committing after `run` call doesn't really work or makes sense to me. The parameters ask for `topic`, `partition` and `offset` , however I only have the `partition` and `offset` inside the `eachMessage` handler. How would I know what these are outside of that handler ?

Comment: @HIT_girl You also have `topic` inside `eachMessage`, as your code shows. Why do you need to disable `autoCommit`, though? You could enable it and set `autoCommitThreshold = 1`, as the answer says, which should do what you want

Comment: what if you want to immediately commit before you process it ?